# Hosting Software Forked from Github locally Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to fork a project from Github to play around with it a bit, but I can't figure out how to run it on a local server.

Here is the github in question: https://github.com/penumbragames/tankanarchy

I downloaded the code, installed node.js and ran "node server.js". Now I can see it in my browser at localhost:5000 but for some reason there is no CSS and the JS isn't running properly either.

Specifically the gives the following errors:

1. "Refused to apply style from "..." because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2. GET client.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (not found)

I've been trying to figure out how to properly run this for a while and am fairly stuck. How do I host/run this?

Here is what it's supposed to look like according to the dev: https://tankanarchy.herokuapp.com/

Comment: There is not enough infos for us to help you. How did you install dependencies? How are you running the code? Where are those errors reported? Did you run webpack and have it installed?

Comment: @Dominik I'm not sure what dependencies are. I'm running the code by opening my terminal, and in the directory with the file, running "node server.js". The errors are reported when I visit the hosted file with my web browser under developer tools. I have installed webpack but am not sure what you mean with running it.

Comment: You run the command `webpack` - as it shows in the readme (although the `npm install` should have done that already because the project has a `postinstall` hook... for me the regular `npm install`+`npm start` works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a short answer after the comments reveled the problem.

After you download the code (look into git and how to clone repositories if you feel like contributing to the code) and you cd into the extracted folder make sure you run `npm install` to install all dependencies. It looks like this repo also have a postinstall hook so after the install it should run webpack to create your bundle (which you are missing now).
After all that run `npm start` and that should start the app that you then can see via the browser as you have already.
This should fix your missing assets.